# Sending file with POST request with HttpUnit

Tags: java, rest, testing, http-unit

we have a REST service, which we would like to test. I thought about using HttpUnit for this purpose. 
We sent POST request to a resource URL and after receiving the request we retrieve the file from request. In our server code we have something like this:

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
FilePart file = body.getFile("upfile");
File pictureFile = file.getFile();
```

In my test I wrote:

```
WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
WebRequest wr = new PostMethodWebRequest("http://linkToOurResource");
File f = new File("testFile.jpg");
wr.selectFile("upfile", f, "multipart/form-data;");
    WebResponse response = wc.getResponse(wr);
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Test functional.AcceptanceTests.testAddingNewClient failed: Parameter 'upfile' is not a file parameter and may not be set to a file value.
```

Any suggestions how to send the file in the POST request to our server?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the httpunit developer FAQ - just search httpunit's Unit Tests to find a fitting source code example:

https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=5051BBF6.70700%40bitplan.com&forum_name=httpunit-develop